# JAX-WS invoke in JSF

Tags: java, web-services, jsf, jsf-2, wsdl

I have converted the WSDL file to java using **wsimport**

it generate two files

**ICalculator**

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.xml.ws.Action;


@WebService(name = "ICalculator", targetNamespace = "http://ws.test.ews/")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public interface ICalculator {


/**
 * 
 * @param arg2
 * @param arg1
 * @param arg0
 * @return
 *     returns int
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "PerformCalculation")
@WebResult(partName = "return")
@Action(input = "http://ws.test.ews/ICalculator/PerformCalculationRequest", output = "http://ws.test.ews/ICalculator/PerformCalculationResponse")
public int performCalculation(
    @WebParam(name = "arg0", partName = "arg0")
    int arg0,
    @WebParam(name = "arg1", partName = "arg1")
    int arg1,
    @WebParam(name = "arg2", partName = "arg2")
    String arg2);

}
```

**CalculatorImplService**

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.WebEndpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;



@WebServiceClient(name = "CalculatorImplService", targetNamespace = "http://ws.test.ews/", wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:9998/ws/calculator?wsdl")
public class CalculatorImplService
extends Service
{

private final static URL CALCULATORIMPLSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
private final static WebServiceException CALCULATORIMPLSERVICE_EXCEPTION;
private final static QName CALCULATORIMPLSERVICE_QNAME = new QName("http://ws.test.ews/", "CalculatorImplService");

static {
    URL url = null;
    WebServiceException e = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://localhost:9998/ws/calculator?wsdl");
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        e = new WebServiceException(ex);
    }
    CALCULATORIMPLSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    CALCULATORIMPLSERVICE_EXCEPTION = e;
}

public CalculatorImplService() {
    super(__getWsdlLocation(), CALCULATORIMPLSERVICE_QNAME);
}

public CalculatorImplService(WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(__getWsdlLocation(), CALCULATORIMPLSERVICE_QNAME, features);
}

public CalculatorImplService(URL wsdlLocation) {
    super(wsdlLocation, CALCULATORIMPLSERVICE_QNAME);
}

public CalculatorImplService(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(wsdlLocation, CALCULATORIMPLSERVICE_QNAME, features);
}

public CalculatorImplService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
}

public CalculatorImplService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature... features) {
    super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     returns ICalculator
 */
@WebEndpoint(name = "CalculatorImplPort")
public ICalculator getCalculatorImplPort() {
    return super.getPort(new QName("http://ws.test.ews/", "CalculatorImplPort"), ICalculator.class);
}

/**
 * 
 * @param features
 *     A list of {@link javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature} to configure on the proxy.  Supported features not in the <code>features</code> parameter will have their default values.
 * @return
 *     returns ICalculator
 */
@WebEndpoint(name = "CalculatorImplPort")
public ICalculator getCalculatorImplPort(WebServiceFeature... features) {
    return super.getPort(new QName("http://ws.test.ews/", "CalculatorImplPort"), ICalculator.class, features);
}

private static URL __getWsdlLocation() {
    if (CALCULATORIMPLSERVICE_EXCEPTION!= null) {
        throw CALCULATORIMPLSERVICE_EXCEPTION;
    }
    return CALCULATORIMPLSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
}

}
```

Now I want to call this WEB SERVICE in JSF. the page (JSF) send three parameters and get the result.

**JSF PAGE**

```
<h:body>
<h3>Calculator</h3>
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{?}"></h:inputText> //for @para1
    <h:inputText value="#{?}"></h:inputText> //for @para2
    <h:inputText value="#{?}"></h:inputText> //for @para3
    <h:commandButton value="Calculate" action="?"></h:commandButton>
</h:form>
<h:panelGroup">
<h4>Results</h4>
<table>
  <tr><td>${?}</td></tr>
</table>
</h:panelGroup>
</h:body>
```

Can I use `@ManagedBean` `@SessionScoped` in CalculatorImplService ? Update me!

How Can I Call this Web Service in JSF ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `@WebServiceRef` annotation to reference the webservice stub class (`CalculatorImplService`) within your managed bean. Using a managed bean class of `MyManagedBean` A rough example of what your code might look like is:

```
@Named("myBean")
@RequestScoped
public class MyManagedBean{

@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation="http://localhost:9998/ws/calculator?wsdl",value=CalculatorImplService.class)   
 ICalculator calculatorService;


 public void calculate(int arg1,int arg2){
    calculatorService.calculate();
 }

}
```

Here, I've used the CDI `@Named` annotation. You're free to use `@ManagedBean` if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks kolossus. If the webservice is in another project (and on another server) it seems inflexible to have the wsdllocation hardcoded everywhere, for example with regards to testing. Would you have an idea to avoid the hardcoding? ;-) I am thinking of an injectable ApplicationScoped bean as "factory" for the Ports, and there won't be any hardcoding (its has an instance of all the different WebServiceClient's, and methods to get the port instances). If you have another idea I can create a new question :-)

Comment: That's a viable option @JaqenH'ghar. A producer method that can load the WSDL location as a JNDI property should work as well (it would be more ideal if we could supply an EL property or JNDI property to the `wsdlLocation` variable with the basic `@WebServiceRef` - haven't looked into whether the spec supports that or not)

Comment: Thanks kolossus, I currenctly have made an EJB layer (to get the pooling), and the instances each have a port retrieved with new CalculatorImplService(). getCalculatorImplPort(). It seems to work fine. Thanks for input :-)